# Variable Digit id autoincrement in psql

Tags: sql, postgresql, auto-increment

I want the column(id) in psql table to be like this 0001,0002,....,0010,0011,.....0100,0101,.....1000,1001,....10000,10001[image]

I used this to create table CREATE TABLE COMPANY(id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT);

Comment: Do not try to alter the structure. Add leading zeros in retrieving query.

Comment: Please do **not** post code as images. See here for more details why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551

Answer (score 2):

Numbers (integers) don't store leading zeros and from a mathematical point of view `1` and `000001` are exactly the same number so there is no need to store it. If you want to *display* the values like that, use `to_char()` to format the values:

```
select to_char(id, 'FM000001') as formatted_id, name
from company;
```

If you don't want to repeat that, create a view:

```
create view company_with_formatted_id
as
select to_char(id, 'FM000001') as formatted_id, name
from company;
```

But I wouldn't do formatting like that in SQL (=in the backend). I would do it in the application that displays the data (=in the frontend).

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to @a_horse_with_no_name's answer is to use `lpad()`:

```
SELECT lpad(id::text,4,'0'),name FROM company;
```

**Demo**:

```
WITH company (id,name) AS (
  VALUES (1,'NAME1'),(2,'NAME2'),(42,'NAME42')  
)
SELECT lpad(id::text,4,'0') AS formatted_id ,name
FROM company;
 formatted_id |  name  
--------------+--------
 0001         | NAME1
 0002         | NAME2
 0042         | NAME42
(3 rows)
```